# Should I perform scheduled content DB SQL backups in addition to scheduled granular backups?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, backup, disaster-recovery

Currently we have a series of scheduled granular backups for the site collection level that use the PS "Backup-SPSite" command (e.g. https://myportal.com). I test these backups frequently, and have found them to work fairly well when restoring to a SP server that is already fully configured the same as the original SP server that was backed up from.

I am wondering if we should also be performing a scheduled backup of the content database specifically via SQL, and if we should, why we would want to consider doing so?

I would also be curious to know how this is different from a granular backup on the site collection level?

Lastly, are there any other backup options that I failing to consider? Our SP site collection is under 10gb and is relatively simple (one physical server, one farm, everything in one spot).

I did take a read over the [Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Backup & Recovery overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663477%28v=office.14%29.aspx) document, but I found it to bring up more questions than it answered:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your storage window allows. More options for backup provides a better, stable and reliable system for restoring data that is corrupted, deleted, or otherwise not available. If one fails, you now have another net of security. I would even go so far to only allow one copy of backups. Obviously, if storage is a pain to keep/get, I wouldn't worry about it.

Edit: I won't say "Always", because it depends on the company's decision whether or not that is something they want to invest in -- another backup failover.

To answer your question about backup types - they are the same, its either granular (site coll) or farm backups. I would also look into farm backups, just in case your whole system crashes--especially if you have a single-server deployment.